# GeoTIFF projections with Python GDAL

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, georeferencing, pyproj

I have a GeoTIFF I imported into Python environment with GDAL. The image has spatial reference data, which are the parameters describing the geo model:

(-104.31292762744124, 0.00030593847623094916, 0.0, 32.77290675637778, 0.0, -0.0002583980094641447)

There is no Projection metadata ( `raster.GetProjection()` ). How can I use these coordinates to create a projection (I want real world coordinates for each pixel location)?

I looked into `osr.SpatialReference` and `pyproj` but I couldn't find any simple or quick explanations. Sorry if this is basic but the online documentation just wasn't helpful for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the **affine transformation matrix**, which describes (in this order in your case):
`[x coordinate of top left corner, pixel width, rotation on x axis, y coordinate of top left corner, rotation on y axis, pixel height]`. Fortunately, this is enough to do what you want.

You might find it a little easier to use [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is an interface to GDAL that is much more user friendly than the GDAL Python bindings.

Here is how it would work:

```py
# you import rasterio like this
import rasterio

# you can open a dataset like this
with rasterio.open("myfile.tif") as dataset:

   # you can see the affine transformation matrix (that you had above) like this:
   print(dataset.transform)

   # you can convert from pixel coordinates to geographical like this:
   # (this example uses the middle of the dataset)
   x, y = dataset.xy(dataset.height // 2, dataset.width // 2)

   # and vice-versa like this:
   # (replace x and y with some coordinates that fall within your dataset)
   row, col = dataset.index(x, y)
```

Note that **Image Space** (pixel) coordinates are in the order y,x (row, col), whereas **coordinate space** uses x, y (lng lat / easting northing). It is also worth knowing that **Image Space** has the origin in the top left, where **Coordinate Space** has the orgin in the bottom left, (hence the pixel height being negative in your dataset).

If you want to add the CRS as well (not necessary for the above) - you could do this:

```py
   # assign CRS as WGS84
   dataset.crs = rasterio.crs.CRS.from_string('EPSG:4326')
```

I have guessed your Coordinate Reference System (CRS) there - if it is a different one to WGS84, then you can just get the correct EPSG code from [here](https://epsg.io/) and swap it out with `4236` in the above snippet.

---

**Alternatively** - if you didn't want to switch to use rasterio, you could do convert from pixel locations (`px_x`, `px_y`) to geographical coordinates using your affine transformation matrix (`t`) like this:

```py
# convert px_x and px_y rto geographical coordinates
x, y = (topleft_x + (px_x * resolution_x), topleft_y - (px_y * resolution_x))

# so in your case, if t is the affine transformation object you had:
x, y = (t[0] + (px_x * t[1]), t[3] - (px_y * t[5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the spatial reference of your data (I'd guess it is [WGS84](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4386/) by taking a look at the origin coordinates you provided and the pixel size), you can set the spatial reference this way:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import osr

# create WGS84 Spatial Reference
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

# open raster in writing mode
fn = r'C:\path\to\my_raster.tif'
ds = gdal.Open(fn, 1)

# set spatial reference
ds.SetProjection(sr.ExportToWkt())

# save raster
ds = None
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and for everyone who provided different ways to solve the problem!

Comment: @RebeccaBrown Hey, Rebbeca, I hope it worked. You might want to check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers